# Accessibility concern about GDSE vote indicator color

Tags: bug, user-interface

The vote indicator coloring on GDSE is more subtle than that of other sites:

GDSE:[image: gdse up]
GDSE Meta:[image: gdse meta up]

SO:[image: so up]
SO Meta:[image: so meta up]

CGSE: [image: CGSE up]
CGSE Meta:[image: cgse meta up]

I'm not sure if it was always like this or if it was something that happened after the [last UI update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394232/228147). I just happened to notice because I've recently undone some of my prior votes when revisiting GDSE posts. I can see a difference, but it's not nearly as noticeable to me as the other sites - the other mainline sites include hue changes on their indicators. Full disclosure: I have some color vision impairment. That said, I don't recall this being an issue for me in the past. Is the UI is working as intended? Even if it is, is this an accessibility concern or is it just an issue for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now. I'm not sure when - I only joined GDSE in early March - but it's currently a nice shade of evergreen for me.

[image: GDSE Upvote]

Comment: You're right! I didn't pick up on it & notice the change until you brought it to my attention. Thanks for answering & bringing it to my attention & mentioning the color by  name.

Comment: You're welcome! It's very similar to the [Pantone color](https://icolorpalette.com/color/pantone-19-5420-tcx) by that name.